# How to create multiple emails to a single recipient with a different file attached on each mail?

Tags: email, automation

I have a big file I need to send via email.
Yes, I know it's stupid, but email is the only method allowed.
I splitted the file using 7zip in order to be able to attach files to the email.
However the files are really a lot.

Is there a way to automatically send an email to one recipient for each part the original file was splitted into?

I am looking for a not-coding solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use smptplib library in python to send mail. you can attach file in `smtpObj.sendmail()`. to send multiple mails create an array of attachments in python

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "YOUR EMAIL"
toaddr = "EMAIL ADDRESS YOU SEND TO"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL"

body = "TEXT YOU WANT TO SEND"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "NAME OF THE FILE WITH ITS EXTENSION"
attachment = open("PATH OF THE FILE", "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")

// Your Attachment
text = msg.as_string()

// Create your attachments array like fileArr[] = [text1,text2,text3.....]
// Iterate through the array to send multiple mails
for attch in fileArr: 
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, attch)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a non-coding solution. Sorry for not specifying